# Copy a directory using NSIS .

Tags: windows, installation, nsis

I can't seem to find any information about how to copy a directory using NSIS ?, i know there is a file command but is there any command to copy a directory .

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The syntax is same for both directory and file, except that you need to specify a directory by providing a `\` at the end. `File` command copies the directory if the specified argument is a directory. For eg, you can do:

```
SetOutPath "outputPath"
File "myDirectory\" #note back slash at the end
```

But that copies only the top level directory. To recursively do it, you have `/r` switch

```
SetOutPath "outputPath"
File /nonfatal /a /r "myDirectory\" #note back slash at the end
```

which copies the contents of `myDirectory` (but not `myDirectory` folder itself). `/nonfatal` ignores without an error if there is no particular directory. `/a` copies file attributes as well. `/x` switch is used to exclude files.

Otherwise,

```
SetOutPath "outputPath\myDirectory"
File /nonfatal /a /r "myDirectory\" #note back slash at the end
```

copies all the contents of `myDirectory` including `myDirectory` folder to `outputPath`.

Comment: Thanks! The last example doesn't seem to work though... To create the folder, I have to use 
SetOutPath $INSTDIR\myDirectory 
and then 
File /a /r "myDirectory\"

Comment: @nawfal, THANK YOU so much for stressing the '\' at the end. It was driving me CRAZY!! I didn't see anything referencing that in the NSIS documentation.

Comment: Important to say it will have a side effect as does pack the directory inside the installer executable on compilation stage.

Answer (score 5):

I found how to do it , sorry for the trouble .

**Extract the files to a directory which can't exist beforehand**

```
CreateDirectory $Installdir\extracting

SetOutPath $Installdir\extracting

File Directory\*
```

Comment: `SetOutPath` already creates the passed directory and subdirectories, so calling CreateDirectory first is not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

The `File` instruction extracts files from your installer and [`CopyFiles`](http://anders_k.users.sourceforge.net/public/NSIS/2.46/Manual.html#copyfiles) copies files and/or directories that already exist on the end-users system (You can use $EXEDIR if you need to copy files off a dvd where your installer is also located...)

Answer (score 0):

The star to match the whole content after the back slash is mandatory. The syntax is the following.

See [the manual](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Docs/Chapter4.html#file) section 4.9.1.6

```
SetOutPath "outputPath\myDirectory"
File /nonfatal /a /r "myDirectory\*"
```

Comment: Why do you mention the star is mandatory after the backslash, but it's not in the code sample you provide?